# Beam-to-Column-Stiffness ratio

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, dynamics

This parameter defines the structural behavior, defining shear or flexure behavior of the structure. 
How do I use this parameter to define the stiffness matrix of the structure to perform dynamic analyses?                  I am performing RSA manually on a stick model, coding in Matlab. This parameter has no units.(dimensionless, its a ratio). RCC model. This is referred to as ALPHA in "APPROXIMATE SEISMIC LATERAL DEFORMATION DEMANDS IN MULTISTORY BUILDINGS By Eduardo Miranda"

Comment: Which program? what are the units? material?

Comment: I am performing RSA manually on a stick model, coding in Matlab. This parameter has no units.(dimensionless, its a ratio). RCC model.

This is referred to as ALPHA in "APPROXIMATE SEISMIC LATERAL DEFORMATION DEMANDS IN
MULTISTORY BUILDINGS
By Eduardo Miranda"

Comment: So, what are the factors that are used to calculate the ratio? If you have them , in the correct units, do the math and enter the value / ratio into the program.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have the ratio, and you are programming it, you have to assume an $E \times l$ for your column or beam and then apply the ratio for the other one (using 1 will do).

However, to define your stiffness matrix you will also need a ratio for your section areas. This is why I would suggest picking 2 realistic sections and approximately find that ratio for each stiffness ratio.